# How can I delete a linked list with a random pointer?

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I want to free the list but I think I did it wrong because even after deletion I have reachable memory blocks.

```
typedef struct TEmployee
{
    struct TEmployee         * m_Next;
    struct TEmployee         * m_Bak;//random pointer
    char                     * m_Name;
} TEMPLOYEE;




void freeList (TEMPLOYEE * src ) {

    while  ( src )  {
        TEmployee * tmp = src ;
        free(src->m_Name);
        src = src -> m_Next ;
        free ( tmp ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I have reachable memory blocks"_ How did you prove this?

Comment: I just used debugger to check but I am not sure.

Comment: Dereferencing any of these pointers after `free()` was called is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Do you have anything to clarify regarding the post? What do you mean by random pointer..how did you find out the reachanble memory blocks

Comment: Random pointer? Please clarify what you mean by random. Your current function is correct **iff** it is called with a pointer to the first element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are calling `freeList` with the pointer to the head of your list, your list is correctly freed.

If `src` doesn't necessarily point to the first element in the list (but to a random element in the list), you can use `m_Back` to traverse back to the first element in the list, and then run your loop to free it.

**Regarding your observation ("I have reachable memory blocks."):**

The reason you think you have reachable memory blocks, is because freeing the memory allocated doesn't necessarily change the memory content itself; meaning, any data you stored on the list while it was allocated, can still be there after you free the memory (and naturally you can't rely on that).

Answer (score 0):

Your function is correct if (**and only if**) it is called with a pointer to the first element in the list.

If you want a function to free the whole list when called with a pointer to an arbitrary element in the list you can do:

```
void freeList (TEMPLOYEE * src ) 
{
    if (src)
    {
        TEmployee* tmp1;

        // Free elements after src
        tmp1 = src->m_Next;
        while (tmp1)  
        {
            TEmployee* tmp2=tmp1;
            free(tmp1->m_Name);
            tmp1 = tmp1->m_Next;
            free(tmp2);
        }

        // Free elements before src
        tmp1 = src->m_Bak;
        while (tmp1)  
        {
            TEmployee* tmp2=tmp1;
            free(tmp1->m_Name);
            tmp1 = tmp1->m_Bak;
            free(tmp2);
        }

        // Free src
        free(src->m_Name);
        free(src);
    }
}
```